# Xamarin Android custom NOTICE file

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

We are developing an application in Xamarin, using the [ZXing.Net.Mobile library](https://github.com/Redth/ZXing.Net.Mobile). This library states that it is based on [ZXing](https://github.com/zxing/zxing). Both libraries are released under Apache v2.0, which states that:

> ```
>   (d) If the Work includes a "NOTICE" text file as part of its
>       distribution, then any Derivative Works that You distribute must
>       include a readable copy of the attribution notices contained
>       within such NOTICE file, excluding those notices that do not
>       pertain to any part of the Derivative Works, in at least one
>       of the following places: within a NOTICE text file distributed
>       as part of the Derivative Works; within the Source form or
>       documentation, if provided along with the Derivative Works; or,
>       within a display generated by the Derivative Works, if and
>       wherever such third-party notices normally appear. The contents
>       of the NOTICE file are for informational purposes only and
>       do not modify the License. You may add Your own attribution
>       notices within Derivative Works that You distribute, alongside
>       or as an addendum to the NOTICE text from the Work, provided
>       that such additional attribution notices cannot be construed
>       as modifying the License.
> ```

ZXing.Net.Mobile does not have a NOTICE file, however ZXing itself **does**. This leads me to believe that ZXing.Net.Mobile is actually violating the apache license, as they themselves state that the library is based on ZXing.

This in turn would still make us responsible for putting their NOTICE file contents in our own NOTICE file if present. It turns out that Xamarin actually generates a NOTICE file, containing Xamarin related licensing.

So, the main question is: **How can I either append text to the Xamarin generated NOTICE file, or replace it by my own? EmbeddedResource does not seem to work.**

Comment: Hello, in my project, I can't find any NOTICE file, could you please tell where I can find the NOTICE file in my xamarin project?

Comment: Hey Joe, we don't have any NOTICE file either. It is generated in the APK when building one in visual studio. Try opening the apk as a zip. Then you will find it :)

Comment: Yes, I found it, I suggest to add Visual Studio tag and msbuild tag for you question.